# is it possible to check URL before running a third party javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what would be the best way to write a script (let's say a third party analytics tracking code, or cookie disclaimer code) that only runs when the page url *isnt* domain dev.website.com or dev2.website.com. Any help regarding this is highly appreciated and will be considered heroic.

So let's say this is the tracking code:

```
<script src="https://cookieprovider.org/script.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="xxyz-key-token123"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function OptanonWrapper() { }

</script>
```

I want to only run this when the website *isnt* dev.mywebsite.com but i want to run it when the url is mywebsite.com.

any help with this will be considered heroic.

Comment: The script can examine `window.location.href` and check whether it matches one of those strings.

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61090433/edit) button to clarify the question, don't put code in comments.

Comment: Please read my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Check this out:

JS VERSION:

```
function tracking(){
        var current_website = window.location.href; 
        if(current_website !== "dev.mywebsite.com") return;
        var script = document.createElement("script"); 
        script.src = "cookieprovider.org"; // set its src to the provided URL 
        script.setAttribute('data-domain-script', 'xxzz-yy32-key');
        document.head.appendChild(script); 
      }

      tracking();
```

PHP Version:

```
<?php

$website_name = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($website_name === "YOUR WEBSITE NAME"): 

?>

<script src="https://cookieprovider.org/script.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="xxyz-key-token123"></script

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Amazing. In addition to script src am i also able to pass this data-domain-script="xxyz-key-token123" variable, that is within the provided tracking code? Basically I am wondering what elements are required to run so that the tracking code works as expected.

Comment: @distantstar yes you can pass any attributes you want to before appending script.

Comment: @distantstar I updated my answer, check out please.

Comment: I can't seem to load the script on the site using the src and attributes...it only seems to run in its original format...any ideas? How do i test this properly?

Comment: @distantstar inspect the element and look to the <head> tag it should be there

Comment: The script is appearing on the page but it's not loading the cookie disclaimer box as expected. The cookie discliamer box loads only when the script is added in its original form. Otherwise the script looks great - to test this, I used test.org as the URL to see if the script runs on dev.mysite.com. Any ideas? Additionally, I am getting an error on Chrome console - illegal return statement.

Comment: @distantstar then you need to load it not from JS, but from PHP or some backend language that you are using.

Comment: That makes sense - what would the PHP version of this script look like?

Comment: So according to the logic, if the website_name matches 'your website name' the scripts will run, or not run?

Comment: @distantstar if the website name matches, then script will be attached, otherwise, not.

Comment: Thanks...so in your php code, is there a way to search for the specific host name, in addition to getting the URL? for example, i want to look for this part only: dev.mywebsite.com. Im assuming $website_name = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; will retrieve the full URL - I would like to limit the query to the host/domain only.

Comment: @distantstar you can use php "substr" function to cut your string that comes from REQUEST_URI